# Append to specific element data from JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I seem to be having an issue with my JSON objects, which is unusual because I have one block of code I know works:

```
function gotoPassage(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < passages.length; i++) {
        if (passages[i].id == id) {
            if (passages[i].bgImage)
                changeBGImage(passages[i].bgImage);

                $("#passage").hide();
                $("#passage").html(passages[i].content);
                $("#passage").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code works as expected, so I assumed the same logic and applied it to my other code, which - by the way - does not render correctly. This code currently looks something like this:

```
function showLoreHistory() {
    $("#lore ul").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < foundLore.length; i++) {
        var content = "<li><a href='javascript:gotoLore(" + foundLore[i].id ");'>";
        for (var j = 0; j < lore.length; j++) {
            if (lore[j].id == foundLore[i].id) {
                content += lore[j].title + "</a></li>";
                $("#lore ul").append(content);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $("#lore").toggle();
}
```

The structure of `lore` and `foundLore` look like this:

```
var lore = [{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "The First War",
    "image": "Images/The First War.jpg",
    "pages": [{
            "content": ""
        }]
}];

var foundLore = [{
    "id": 0
}];
```

I was thinking of iterating through the keys of each JSON object, but found that it looked ugly, and considering my previous logic for showing passages worked assumed that the same logic would work for my Lore, but it does not seem to.

I would come up with a JSFiddle but unfortunately I rely on too many local resources to get it working properly without sacrificing code, which would defeat the point of me explaining the issue.

EDIT: If I comment out the for loops in the function `showLoreHistory`, the page will render correctly as expected in the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKfoe.png).

EDIT 2: What I am trying to do is get the values from the above JSON object and adding the values to HTML, under a div tag namely `lore` - which is hidden by default.

The Div tag, with its content, looks like this:

```
<div id="lore">
    <h1>Lore</h1>
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>
```

If you have any solutions regarding this, I would strongly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"?...  Doesn't show on the screen? or doesn't find the right value(s)? or...?

Comment: Sorry, by do not work, I mean the page renders incorrectly. I will re-edit my "do not work" part.

Comment: What is "ugly"? How does an ugly JSON object look like? Please, be more specific, show your JS object, and how you obtain it, and what you expect to obtain instead. Marked for closing for "unclear what you're asking"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

```
var content = "<li><a href='javascript:gotoLore(" + foundLore[i].id ");'>";
```

is missing a '+' after foundLore[i].id

Also, the toggle is probably not what you want.  I think you should hide it at the beginning of the function, then show it at the end like in your other function where you show the image.

If you open developer tools (f12 or ctrl+shift+j) it will show you errors like that.

p.s. it took literally under 2 minutes to make a fiddle for me to find the problem..  Give it a shot next time.

http://jsfiddle.net/8cr9t1zy/2/
You have to hit the button twice because of the toggle() thing I mentioned above.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I managed to miss that... I guess I needed more than one pair of eyes to figure that out. Thank you :) +1